# Error while sending QUERY packet

Tags: php, mysql

i was trying to insert some data into the database but i got this error "**Error while sending QUERY packet**"

```
$insertDeta = $conPat->prepare("insert into table1(data) VALUES(:data)");
$insertDeta->bindParam(':data',$data);
$conPat->beginTransaction();    
    $insertDeta->execute();
$conPat->commit();
```

but what i think the problem is that size of the **data** is over 16MB.
the data type of the column is set as **longtext**, which i think can keep data as big as 4GB.

I dont know if PDOs is having problems running the query or transfering 16MB of data to the database.
Thats the only guess i can make as mysql might send the data in *packets* and the packet cannot hold data as large as 16MB.

Comment: what you did finaly to solve the issuse ? i have the same

Answer (score 52):

You guessed right MySQL have limitation for size of data, you need to break your query in small group of records or you can Change your max_allowed_packet by using `SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=524288000;`

Comment: i set max_allowed_packet to 256M in **my.ini** file, but it didnt work.

Comment: and if i fire a query to SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=524288000; i get this error "_check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=524288000' at line 1_"

Comment: Is there anyway to log the query which triggered this warn?

Comment: wow cool, it works for me. i though it is from the logs, and also make sure to check your post_max_size and upload_max_filesize in php.ini

Answer (score 34):

You can solve this problem by following few steps:

1) open your terminal window

2) please write following command in your terminal

```
ssh root@yourIP port
```

3) Enter root password

4) Now edit your server my.cnf file using below command

```
nano /etc/my.cnf
```

if command is not recognized do this first or try vi then repeat: yum install nano.

**OR**

```
  vi /etc/my.cnf
```

5) Add the line under the [MYSQLD] section. :

```
max_allowed_packet=524288000 (obviously adjust size for whatever you need) 
wait_timeout = 100
```

6) Control + O (save)  then ENTER (confirm) then Control + X (exit file)

7) Then restart your mysql server by following command

```
/etc/init.d/mysql stop
/etc/init.d/mysql start
```

8)  You can verify by going into PHPMyAdmin or opening a SQL command window and executing:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet'
```

This works for me. I hope it should work for you.

Comment: The [default value](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) for `wait_timeout` is 28800 seconds. Why would you lower it to 100?

Comment: Any answer to the comment above? I'd be interested in learning why 100 only... I have 500MB in max_allowed_packet, wait_timeout 100 and it is still crashing with the same error message. What could it be?

Comment: Perhaps,100 is higher than some host's custom default value? But that is just a guess.

Comment: Note If you're on AWS: I had to do sudo vi /etc/my.cnf and to restart mysql I had to instead do sudo service mysqld restart

Answer (score 16):

You may also have this error if the variable `wait_timeout` is too low.

If so, you may set it higher like that:

```
SET GLOBAL wait_timeout=10;
```

This was the solution for the same error in my case.

Comment: Watch out for low values with this variable. I spent way too much time only to realize that somewhere deep in a script was sleep(70); which was causing lost DB connection and therefore “Error while sending QUERY packet”. So either consider setting it up at least as minutes or ping() your DB to keep the connection alive.

Answer (score 4):

In `/etc/my.cnf` add:

```
  max_allowed_packet=32M
```

It worked for me.  You can verify by going into PHPMyAdmin and opening a SQL command window and executing:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE  'max_allowed_packet'
```

Answer (score 4):

I encountered a rare edge case in cygwin, where I would get this error when doing `exec('rsync');` somewhere before the query. Might be a general PHP problem, but I could only reproduce this in cygwin with rsync.

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=mysql', 'root');
var_dump($pdo->query('SELECT * FROM db'));
exec('rsync');
var_dump($pdo->query('SELECT * FROM db'));
```

produces

```
object(PDOStatement)#2 (1) {
   ["queryString"]=>
   string(16) "SELECT * FROM db"
}
PHP Warning:  Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=15036 in test.php on line 5
bool(false)
```

Bug reported in https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2017-05/msg00272.html

Comment: get the same bug

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have the `WHERE` clause in an `INSERT` statement.

`insert into table1(data) VALUES(:data) where sno ='45830'`

Should be

`insert into table1(data) VALUES(:data)`

---

**Update**: You have removed that from your code (I assume you copied the code in wrong). You want to increase your allowed packet size:

`SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=32M`

Change the `32M` (32 megabytes) up/down as required. [Here is a link to the MySQL documentation on the subject.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/program-variables.html)

Comment: SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=32M isnt working in mysql, it says invalid argument.   

but if i fire a query to SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=524288000; i get this error "check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=524288000' at line 1"

Comment: You can run `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet'` to see what your max value actually is. Are you on a shared host? If yes then it might be disabled for you.

Comment: Is this persistent or do you have to do this again after mysql restarts?

Comment: @OgierSchelvis That is documented in *literally* the first sentence in the link I posted above.

Comment: @cjhill Well sorry about that, let me read the entire docs first before I ask a casual common question that is going to help people faster when answered here.

Comment: this is wrong - even the page you linked says specifically **"Suffixes for specifying a value multiplier can be used when setting a variable at server startup, but not to set the value with SET at runtime"**.  In other words you can do `32*1024*1024` but *not* `32M`.

Answer (score 0):

If inserting 'too much data' fails due to the `max_allowed_packet` setting of the database server, the following warning is raised:

```
SQLSTATE[08S01]: Communication link failure: 1153 Got a packet bigger than 
'max_allowed_packet' bytes
```

If this warning is catched as exception (due to the set error handler), the database connection is (probably) lost but the application doesn't know about this (failing inserts can have several causes).
The next query in line, which can be as simple as:

```
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
```

Will then fail with the error this SO-question started:

```
Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=18486
```

Simple test script to reproduce my explanation, try it with and without the error handler to see the difference in impact:

```
set_error_handler(function($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, array $errcontext) {
    // error was suppressed with the @-operator
    if (0 === error_reporting()) {
        return false;
    }

    throw new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
});

try
{
    // $oDb is instance of PDO
    var_dump($oDb->query('SELECT 1 FROM DUAL'));

    $oStatement = $oDb->prepare('INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `message`) VALUES (NULL, :message);');
    $oStatement->bindParam(':message', $largetext, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    var_dump($oStatement->execute());
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    $e->getMessage();
}
var_dump($oDb->query('SELECT 2 FROM DUAL'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Had such a problem when executing forking in php for command line. In my case from time to time the php killed the child process. To fix this, just wait for the process to complete using the command **pcntl_wait($status);**

here's a piece of code for a visual example:

```
    #!/bin/php -n
    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
    ini_set("log_errors", 1);
    ini_set('error_log', '/media/logs/php/fork.log');
    $ski = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 5)), 0, 5);
    error_log(getmypid().' '.$ski.' start my php');

    $pid = pcntl_fork();
    if($pid) {
    error_log(getmypid().' '.$ski.' start 2');
    // Wait for children to return. Otherwise they 
    // would turn into "Zombie" processes
    // !!!!!! add this !!!!!!
    pcntl_wait($status);
    // !!!!!! add this !!!!!!
    } else {
    error_log(getmypid().' '.$ski.' start 3');
    //[03-Apr-2020 12:13:47 UTC] PHP Warning:  Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=18048 in /speed/sport/fortest.php on line 22457
    mysqli_query($con,$query,MYSQLI_ASYNC);
error_log(getmypid().' '.$ski.' sleep child');
  sleep(15);
    exit;
    } 

   error_log(getmypid().' '.$ski.'end my php');
    exit(0);
    ?>
```