# how to solve mysql query error on crontab?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, cron

when i run this query manually it work good but via `crontab` i get mysql error

> Warning:  PHP Warning:  mysql_query(): MySQL server has gone away

```
 $query="set @c=0;";
 $result=mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: **Stop** using deprcated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*`or `PDO`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30753674/error-while-sending-query-packet

Comment: @Jens PDO  dose not support set var

Comment: @chenyb999 i use max time limit