# How to find out the actual reason for PHP warning `Error while sending QUERY packet`?

Tags: php, mysql, error-logging, error-log

Yesterday the following messages showed up in my PHP logs:

```
[10-Apr-2016 11:51:32 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Warning:  Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=31184 in /tools/stat.php on line 322
[10-Apr-2016 11:51:33 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Warning:  Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=31200 in /tools/stat.php on line 322
[10-Apr-2016 11:51:35 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Warning:  Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=31209 in /tools/stat.php on line 322
[10-Apr-2016 11:51:40 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Warning:  Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=31226 in /tools/stat.php on line 322
[10-Apr-2016 11:53:17 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Warning:  Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=32184 in /tools/stat.php on line 322
[10-Apr-2016 11:53:24 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Warning:  Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=32207 in /tools/stat.php on line 322
[10-Apr-2016 11:53:27 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Warning:  Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=32217 in /tools/stat.php on line 322
[10-Apr-2016 11:53:28 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Warning:  Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=32225 in /tools/stat.php on line 322
[10-Apr-2016 11:53:30 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Warning:  Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=32227 in /tools/stat.php on line 322
[10-Apr-2016 11:53:32 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Warning:  Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=32242 in /tools/stat.php on line 322
```

The query itself is actually quite short, so that [Error while sending QUERY packet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30753674/error-while-sending-query-packet) did not help me.

Some facts about the server/scripts:

- Yesterday I changed from `PHP 5.4.45` to `PHP 5.5.34`.
- The MySQL server on that machine is: `5.1.73-1+deb6u1`
- The MySQL client on that machine is: `mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503`
- I'm ignoring all deprecated warnings so they don't show up in the PHP logs.
- I'm still sending MySQL requests using `mysql_query()` (I'm about to change this soon).

Now is there a way to find out what happened in that time? It did not happen again, yet.

Do you have any idea what might have caused this error an how to verfiy this?

ADDITION for `loka_bolka`:

```
mysql_query("
    UPDATE
        `tablename`
    SET
        ".$query."
    WHERE
        `user` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($user)."'
    LIMIT 1
"); // This is line 322
```

Comment: show us your `/tools/stat.php` what is in `line 322`?

Comment: @lolka_bolka: The problem only occurred for a couple of minutes. the other `400,000` queries since yesterday where fine.

Comment: I have no idea. Maybe this helps, maybe timeout happens for some reason for some queries: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30753674/error-while-sending-query-packet