# Can't upload new product image backend prestashop

Tags: prestashop

I need a little help here, i hope someone here can help me for a hint or clue.

First of all, I'm not programmer. I'm just web admin who can use cms and basic html.

I was using **PrestaShop** for my online shop. In the backend, I can't upload new product image anymore.

The error just blank without any sign for me. Here for the screenshot:

[image: here for the screenshot]

I appreciate it, if someone can help me, thanks, and sorry for my english.

Comment: please check permission for your /img folder in the root directory of PrestaShop.

Comment: Its 755, do i need to change it?

Comment: in that case check ownership as well...

Comment: how do i check my ownership? i can access anything without trouble , and i use go daddy for my hosting

Comment: Try to use FileZilla and connect with FTP. There you can see your files permissions and owners.

Comment: i already set img folder to 777 , the ownership also all checked

Comment: Hello. If you uploaded images before and now you can't then your problem is related to some changes in your shop. The most common could be a new module, a hacking, a configuration or changes in files directly. Anyway, I recommend you to active DEBUG MODE in Prestashop. Check what error details appear and let me know so I can help you. Good luck.

Comment: hello @PixelWeb ,i found an error written like this, "json.parse unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the json data" ,
could you give me an advice to fix this?

Comment: @PixelWeb and 1 more error "public_html/classes/db/DbPDO.php
[2] Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=623277"

Answer (score 0):

@PanjiWiyono This errors don't really give us a quality information, but this is a start. In your JS code should be a ajax query that has an error when converting results to json (first error). You should check what's the exact error that this request is returning by inspecting in browser developer console.

If you detect that the second error is in fact, the response of this ajax query, well now we almost have the problem.

The second error should be related to data size. Check this: [Error while sending QUERY packet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30753674/error-while-sending-query-packet)

Anyway, you should check `DbPDO.php` class. You can use `debug_backtrace` function to display the complete stack, but definitly if error is related to a basic PHP class issue you will have not help knowing wich classes are in calling stack.

Good luck.

Answer (score -2):

Simple solution

maybe a extra module is in a conflict with the prestashop core files. go to advanced parameters, performance and disable third party modules  and try again.
 other option is reupload admin folder with other name and 
js folder check again
hope it will work for you