# Installation issue c5 8.3.1

Tags: failed-installation, concrete5-8.x

Try to install a new c5-8.3.1 without result. I try php 5.6.32 and php 7.0.26 with the same errors.

When I try to install with the full site, Installation crashes during the import files session with error:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.fslName AS fslName_1, t0.fslConfiguration AS fslConfiguration_2, t0.fslID AS fslID_3, t0.fslIsDefault AS fslIsDefault_4 FROM FileStorageLocations t0 WHERE t0.fslIsDefault = ? LIMIT 1' with params [1]: Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=5877.
```

Trace:

> ## 0 /home/u960240172/public_html/new/concrete/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(855):
>
> Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException::driverExceptionDuringQuery(Object(Concrete\Core\Database\Driver\PDOMySqlConcrete5\Driver),
>   Object(Whoops\Exception\ErrorException), 'SELECT t0.fslNa...', Array) 
>   .. follows 30 traces

When I try the Empty site option, it goes through, but when I log in as an Admin I get another error:

```
An unexpected error occurred.
```

An exception occurred while executing 'SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE Table_type = 'BASE TABLE'': SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

This is a MySQL server error, not concrete5's.

See: Error while sending QUERY packet

[Error while sending QUERY packet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30753674/error-while-sending-query-packet)