# Wordpress PHP Warning: Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=7350

Tags: database, wordpress

“Warning: Error while sending QUERY packet.”

I am getting this error again and again. i contact to my host and they set all configuration according to need but still getting same error and my website is not work properly because of this error.
Please let me know if you have any solution regarding this error.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error while sending QUERY packet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30753674/error-while-sending-query-packet)

Comment: Its due to server configuration, max_allowed_packet_size is set to low in your case.