# PHP / MySQL Insert with ~400,000 characters failing as cron job

Tags: php, mysql

I have a long insert statement with 400,000 characters that does not work when I run it from a script as

`$result = $conn->query($sqlfinal);`

I echo the sql statement onto the page, it only takes about 20 seconds so it's not a script timeout issue. I copy and paste that result into PhpMyAdmin and it works fine there.

The logs say **Error while sending QUERY packet** and it works fine when I reduce it to a smaller query with the same syntax of around 25,000 characters. I'm using Hostinger for my hosting provider, I'm trying to figure out if I'm hitting a Hostinger restriction, or a PHP restriction?

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30753674/error-while-sending-query-packet

Comment: See the answer about setting `max_allowed_packet`.

Comment: I tried to write a record with 600,000 characters in my localhost and it works fine.